# Check collision in a bubble grid

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x

I am new in game development. I am creating a bubble shooting game in x-code using cocos2dx.

All things are working properly but sometimes the collision does not work. The `playerBuble` does not collide in the last line, it collides with the last one. Where’s the problem in my code?

```
bool collided = false;
int collidedX = 0;
int collidedY = 0;

CCPoint playerBubblePosition = playerBubble->getPosition();

// Breadth first Search through the array starting from the bottom left
for (int y = GRID_HEIGHT-1; y >= 0; y--)
{
    if (collided)
        break;
    int maxWidth = GRID_WIDTH;
    if (y % 2 != 0) // odd rows have GRID_WIDTH -1 bubbles
    {
        maxWidth -= 1;
    }
    for (int x = 0; x < maxWidth; x++)
    {
        Bubble* bubble = m_pBubbles[x][y];
        //
        if ((y != 0 &&( bubble->getType() == EMPTY) || bubble->getFalling()) 
            continue;
        if ((ccpDistance(bubble->getPosition(), (playerBubblePosition)) < (BUBBLE_RADIUS))
        {
            collidedX = x;
            collidedY = y;
            collided = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain " the playerbuble not colliding in last line it's colliding with last one" a bit more.

Comment: Maybe an illustrative image would help us understand. You are not allowed to post posts with images yet, but you can link to them and we’ll edit them in for you.

Comment: The last two if statements have one more opening parentheses than the closing ones.

Comment: i am creating a grid and giving the type 1 to 9, and suppose the last bubble position is x=2 &y=7.but the player bubble is collided with the bubble x=2 & y=6 .

And I printed the type of bubble using cclog it's shows the type between 1 to 9.